# Get color from identifier in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get a color value from its string name.

```
private fun getColor(ctx: Context, colorName: String) = ctx.resources.getIdentifier(colorName, "color", ctx.packageName)
```

I can get the RGB values but the upper bits (alpha) are stuck at 7F max because of kotlin's Int being different from java int.

How can I get the right alpha when my color is for example

```
<color name="text_disabled">#B3FFFFFF</color>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a bit more of your code? Also the fun name is missleading: `getColorResource` might be better. `getIdentifier` doesn't return a color.

Comment: Yes it's confusing I use it like this val textColor: Int = getColor(ctx, "text_color")

Comment: So you're actually calling `getColor` with the result as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

Comment: works with ContextCompat, I renamed getColor to getColorIdentifier for clarity. Thanks guys